# FPT100B alternative

Tags: phototransistor, optical-fibre, alternatives

I have a board that uses an FPT100B and a 271 chip as fibre optic receiver. The fibre optic receives red light, not IR. The FPT100B is not working. I am pretty clueless as to what I can use as an alternative. Is there a direct substitute currently available?

Addendum: Just to add as I seem to have gotten a down vote. I have spent several hours trying to find the original component and then a direct alternative. The MEL11 seems like it might work but is also discontinued. I am a school teacher not an electrical engineer and it is not obvious to me what I should be looking for. Help gratefully received.

[image: Front of board]
[image: Back of board]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBP8AC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Much better! The FPT100B looks like a 40 year old device and a phototransistor, not a photodiode. Your test board seems made for photodiodes. What’s your requirements on sensitivity, wavelength and speed?

Comment: It's a school demo. We use it to send an AM radio signal via a transmitter board, through optical fibre to the receiver. Receiver gets passed to a power amp and then to a speaker. Demonstrates transfer of the radio signal via fibre optic.
 
I don't think speed is an issue anything that can cope with audio frequencies would do fine. So up to ~18kHz. The transmitter just uses a red LED so it is about 630nm. 
I would prefer something not super selective. 
As for sensitivity I'm not sure. The FPT100B worked well so as similar as possible to that.

Comment: Clarification the radio signal is audio when it is transmitted. through the fibre. It is demodulated prior to sending into the fibre.

Comment: Any particular fiber type in mind? 1 mm TosLink fiber ok? https://www.firecomms.com/contentFiles/technicalDocuments/FB00AKAR%20Datasheet%20Revision%20E.pdf

Comment: I have a fibre, I really want to desolder the existing FPT100B and solder something else in its place if possible.

Comment: Which fiber? Are you coupling the fiber to the detector by just holding them against each other?

Comment: Exactly what fibre is lost to the mysteries of time. It is about 4m of 1mm fibre with a black plastic cladding. Seems to have very good transmission in the 630nm region....  The photodiode/phototransistor is under the metal cone you see in the picture. The fibre fits through the hole in the top of the cone and this holds the fibre up against the component. It couples well enough for demo purposes. The point is not to make something you would want to use long term but to demonstrate the principal. It is a bit noisy.

Comment: Find an NPN transistor in a metal can TO-18 package (2N2222, whatever). Gently grind/file/saw the top off. Voila - generic "phototransistor".

Answer (score 5):

[BPW76A and BPW76B](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81526/bpw76.pdf) are in-production devices that should be acceptable in this application. The package has roughly same dimensions.

The 4.7kohm resistor may need some adjustment, but otherwise it looks like it'd all work.

It may also help to put a 0.1uF ceramic axial capacitor between the supply and ground pins on the op-amp - on the bottom side of the board. It's not a very fast one, but still - the wiring will have plenty of inductance. So that could be a nice mod.

The kit is a part of the now-largely-eroded Alpha series of products from Unilab.

> Exactly what fibre is lost to the mysteries of time.

It looks like [Philip Harris took over Unilab](https://www.philipharris.co.uk/help-and-advice/about/unilab) and they provide some support/spares contacts. Given that those products were presumably widely used, they may even know the answers you need off the top of their head (one hopes).

According to [Unilab's 2016-2017 Catalog](https://archive.org/details/UnilabCatalogue20162017/page/n59/mode/2up), the "simple" fiber optic kit got at some point superseded by the Comprehensive Fiber Optics Kit, F4H28627. The design is in the same spirit and seems to use the same fiber optic.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is from the old Alpha kit. I have buckets of the stuff! Not sure whether the fibre is original or was replaced at some point. I have tried contacting the unilab in the past..... they haven't been super helpful. Generally they seem to prefer you to replace, rather than service and repair, at considerably more expense. The new fibre optic kit looks interesting but if the current kit can be repaired for a few pounds that is a better route than splashing a lot of money on something that is largely a one trick pony. 
Thanks I will try the parts you have suggested. Much appreciated.

Comment: I see! it is an inverting amplifier and if I needed more gain then I can increase the value of the 4.7K resistor?

Comment: @user3604932 Yes, exactly. The sensitivity of BPW76 is in the same ballpark as that of FPT100B, so there may be no need to change it. If you have more of those receivers, you may measure their output amplitude, and set the fixed board to act the same.